# How do you bind multiple colors to fill a rectangle in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am binding an ItemsControl to an observable collection called SwatchThumbnails which will contain the data in order to generate rectangles. The rectangle can have between 1-3 colors associated with it, and needs to display that many colors when it renders. I think I understand how to bind just one color to the fill, but I need a way to bind up to three and have them display evenly. How can this be done?

Here is my XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="sv_Thumbnails" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ug_Thumbnails" ItemsSource="{Binding SwatchThumbnails, ElementName=mainWindow}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="6" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5" Cursor="Hand">
                  <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="{Binding Color}" Margin="0 0 5 0" />
                </UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I was originally inserting the rectangle shape into the UniformGrid via C# code, so I have the original code that was written for splitting out the colors. Basically, this was the original code that I had for generating the rectangles:

```
        System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle swatch = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        swatch.Width = 50;
        swatch.Height = 50;
        swatch.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 5, 0);
        swatch.StrokeThickness = 1;
        swatch.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Gray;
        swatch.Name = "s_" + _name.ToString();
        double groupsize = 100 / _colors.Count();
        DrawingBrush blackBrush = new DrawingBrush();
        DrawingGroup checkersDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
        List<SolidColorBrush> brushes = _colors;
        double location = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _colors.Count(); i++)
        {
            GeometryDrawing drawing = new GeometryDrawing(brushes[i], null,
                new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, location, groupsize, groupsize)));
            checkersDrawingGroup.Children.Add(drawing);
            location += groupsize;
        }
        blackBrush.Drawing = checkersDrawingGroup;
        swatch.Fill = blackBrush;
        swatch.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(loadSwatchResources);
```

Lastly, here's my observable collection and swatch thumbnail definition.

```
    private ObservableCollection<SwatchThumbnail> swatchThumbnails = new ObservableCollection<SwatchThumbnail>();
    public ObservableCollection<SwatchThumbnail> SwatchThumbnails 
    {
        get { return swatchThumbnails; }
        set { swatchThumbnails = value; }
    }

public class SwatchThumbnail : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Color> colors { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Background you want for each thumbnail in fact looks like a vertical `LinearGradientBrush` so the best choice here is `LinearGradientBrush`, not `DrawingBrush` which is too complicated (and overkill) for this scenario. You need some `Colors` property (with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented) holding the Colors range. To convert this to a `LinearGradientBrush`, you need a `Converter`. I understand that all the color bands should have equal Height (and full Width). Fortunately that the `Offset` in LinearGradientBrush is relative (by some ratio) to the whole Height, so we don't need any info on the actual Height of the related Rectangle. Here is the Converter class:

```
public class ColorsToLinearGradientBrushConverter : IValueConverter {
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                                        CultureInfo culture){
      var colors = (List<Color>) value;
      var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(){ StartPoint = new Point(),
                                             EndPoint = new Point(0,1)};
      var w = 1d / colors.Count;
      for(var i = 0; i < colors.Count - 1; i++){
         var offset = w * (i+1);
         var stop1 = new GradientStop(colors[i], offset);
         var stop2 = new GradientStop(colors[i+1], offset);
         brush.GradientStops.Add(stop1);
         brush.GradientStops.Add(stop2);
      }
      return brush;
   }
   //this way back is not needed (bind OneWay)
   public object ConvertBack(object value Type targetType, object parameter,
                                                           CultureInfo culture){
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Note that the `Colors` property should have Type of `List<Color>` (your original property has Type of `List<SolidColorBrush>`).

Define your Converter as some Resource in your XAML and use it normally for the Binding (I hope you know this). Here is the XAML code:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="sv_Thumbnails" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <ScrollViewer.Resources>
     <local:ColorsToLinearGradientBrushConverter x:Key="brushConverter"/>
   </ScrollViewer.Resources>
   <ItemsControl x:Name="ug_Thumbnails" ItemsSource="{Binding SwatchThumbnails, 
                                                      ElementName=mainWindow}">
     <!--ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="6" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5" Cursor="Hand">
            </UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel-->

     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="{Binding Colors,
                                     Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}" 
                         Margin="0 0 5 0" />
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Note that you have to use some `ItemTemplate` here, your original XAML just has `ItemsPanel` which changes the whole container of the items. If this is what you want, just specify that panel normally but remember that it's just related to ***how to arrange and layout*** the items. That means we cannot bind Background for each item based on just that.

***Update***: I assumed that you implemented the `SwatchThumbnail` properly. But looks like you've not. So try the following implementation instead to see if it works:

```
public class SwatchThumbnail : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop){
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if(handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
  }
  string _name;
  public string name {
    get { return _name;}
    set { 
       if(_name != value) {
          _name = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("name");
       }
    }
  }
  List<SolidColorBrush> _colors;
  public List<SolidColorBrush> colors {
    get {
       return _colors;
    }
    set {
       _colors = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("colors");
    }
  }
  bool _selected;
  public bool selected {
    get {
       return selected;
    }
    set {
       if(_selected != value){
          _selected = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("selected");
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry for my delay. I am trying your solution but the Rectangle line item is giving me an error. "Property ItemsTemplate does not support value of type "rectangle". This seems really weird to me.

Comment: @Yecats yes, it's my silly mistake, plz see the updated code.

Comment: Thanks it gets me past the error but I am having a trouble with the binding I think. I have confirmed that the observablecollection has three items in it. When I run the program though, nothing is displayed. The break point on the converter never triggers which makes me think that binding is off perhaps?

Comment: @Yecats how do you implement the class `SwatchThumbnail`? I mean did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or at least let it inherit from some base class implementing that interface)? Also try viewing the ***Output*** window to see if there is any error notified there. Of course if the Converter is not triggered, there won't be anything  rendered.

Comment: Updated above. I think I did it wrong but I'm still reading on how you are supposed to do it. Ah, yes there's an error: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=mainWindow'. BindingExpression:Path=SwatchThumbnails; DataItem=null; target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name='ug_Thumbnails'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: @Yecats have you given some `Name` for your Window? that error means the Source for the Binding cannot be determine. The Window should have name of `mainWindow`, the `ScrollViewer` should be a child or descendant of the Window (so that the Binding can target the window using Binding with `ElementName`).

Comment: I believe so - mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Class="S4Studio.MainWindow"
        x:Name="mainWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="The S4 Studio" MinHeight="705" MinWidth="920" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Icon="icon.png" Width="920" Height="705" Closing="mainWindow_Closing"> If I remove the elementName piece i don't get the error but it still doesn't have anything appear / call the controller

Comment: @Yecats is the `ScrollViewer` placed in such as some `UserControl`? normally when this problem occurs, there should be some UserControl involved here.

Comment: It's inside of a groupbox which is inside of a grid.

Comment: If i programmatically set the dataContext to the itemsControl I can see that the dataContext has 3 items via the backend.. but nothing renders.

Comment: @Yecats your current issue is really strange and weird. Technically it would happen when the inner elements (the ItemsControl) have been  loaded ***but*** the container control (the `Window`) has been not. However it's strange that I've never encountered such a case with a `Window`, it does happens to a `UserControl`. I also see this strange namespace defined in your Window markup `mc:Ignorable="d"`, the prefix `mc` of course should be declared somewhere. That is auto-generated only for a `UserControl`, not for a `Window`. Unless you added that manually yourself.

Comment: @Yecats if setting `DataContext` in code behind and remove the `ElementName` makes the first Binding work, you can try updating your `SwatchThumbnail` class to the code I posted in the update part.

Comment: Ok, I didn't need to implement the INotifiyPropertyChanged. Instead, I changed the c# to not set the DataContext but to set the  ItemSource and it started working. :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the easiest way would be to use a `DrawingBrush` instead of a `SolidColorBrush`.

Your DrawingBrush would describe the pattern you use to fill your Rectangle (in your case, you would use your three SolidColor brushes to draw the content of the DrawingBrush).
The `Fill` property of your rectangle should then be bound to the DrawingBrush.

See a description on how to use a DrawingBrush as Rectangle fill [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingbrush(v=vs.110).aspx).